# how to make sure a String input is not a number?

Tags: java

I am using a do..while loop and in my while I have

```
while (intOne != intTwo && colorOne != 0 && colorTwo != 0);
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error. "Incompatible operand types String and int"

I know it's because my colorOne and colorTwo are strings and I am trying to say they are not equal to an int.

I think it has something to do with casting and stuff but I am new to this and need help please!

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon at the end of your `while` statement? If it's a busy wait loop, at least use `Thread.sleep`  in the body.

Comment: your Strings `colorOne` and `colorTwo` can (by design) *never* be equal to an int.. even if `colorOne="2"` `(colorOne==2)` will never be true

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the int from your String:

```
Integer.parseInt( colorOne )
```

So your code would look like this:

```
while (intOne != intTwo && Integer.parseInt( colorOne ) 
    != 0 && Integer.parseInt( colorTwo ) != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need conversion. Just control for string matches like:

```
while (intOne != intTwo && !colorOne.equals("0") && !colorTwo.equals("0"));
```

By this, the code won't throw possible string to integer conversion exceptions. One note that `==` and `!=` operators don't work for string comparison in general terms, they compare the reference equality in Java.

Comment: Interesting approach.

Comment: the interesting thing is people are giving conversion answers according to that sentence in the question for such a simple task :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to convert a string to an integer:

```
Integer.parseInt(colorOne)
```

You would also need to check that colorOne is actually an integer, e.g. catch the exception thrown when it isn't and print out an error message there.